# D3 axis without using d3.svg.axis() method

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

[image]I am a beginner in D3.js . I need to draw a graph with axis as per below image.Any working fiddle will help me a lot.

I have checked the below fiddle but not sure how to tweak it as per my requirement.

Comment: There's no image or link to a fiddle in your post.

Comment: added the image.plz help.

Comment: You can use the scale's `ticks(number)` method to get the tick positions, then use the scale itself to position them and draw the circles and labels.  If you want more specific help, you'll need to post the code of what you've tried and explain why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the scale (which is completely independent from the axis) and use its parameters to create the svg elements for your axis; in your case the horizontal line and a circle + text as ticks.
Specifically, you could use the scale `range()` to get the horizontal line length; and the scale `ticks(n)` functions to get `n` evenly spaced points in the domain of the scale. By passing these points to the scale you get the x coordinate to use for your ticks.

```
xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0.0, 1.0]).range([0, width]);
var axis = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xaxis');

axis.append('line').attr({
    'x1': xScale.range()[0],
    'y1': height,
    'x2': xScale.range()[1],
    'y2': height
});

ticks = axis.selectAll('.ticks')
    .data(xScale.ticks(10))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'tick');

ticks.append('circle')
    .attr({
        'cx': function(d) { return xScale(d); },
        'cy': height,
        'r': 5
    });

ticks.append('text')
    .attr({
        'x': function(d) { return xScale(d); },
        'y': height,
        'dy': 20 // Move the text a little under the line
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Here is a minimal working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LeartS/yGesr/